# Why is $\int_0^\frac{1}{2} r\cdot\log(|\log(r)|)dr$ finite?

Tags: calculus

How can I show, that the integral $$\int_0^\frac{1}{2} r\cdot\log(|\log(r)|)dr$$ is finite? My idea is to show, that $$\log(|\log(r)|)\le \frac{1}{r}$$ for all $r\in(0,\frac{1}{2}$), but how can I prove it?

Comment: Your idea will work. You have to use (a precise version of) the fact that $|\log(t)|\to \infty$ slower than any $t^{-n}$ as $t\to 0$. Alternatively, you could calculate the limit of the integrand $f(r)$ as $r \to 0$ and conclude $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Yes both of those ideas came into my mind. Actually I had calculated the limit by using l'Hospital and the limit is 0. Also a plot shows, that this function is bounded, but how precisely could I show this?

Comment: We have a theorem that says continuous functions on closed intervals are bounded. If you define $f(r) = r \log(|\log(r)|)$ when $r\neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$, then $f$ is continuous on $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: Oh, yes, thats true. So we already know that $f$ is continuous on $(0,\frac{1}{2}]$ since it is a product of continuous functions with values in $\mathbb{R}$. The only missing point would be $0$. Using l'Hospital we we have a continuous bounded function on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Alternatively one shoes: $\forall x\in(0,\frac{1}{2})\exists!z\in(2,\infty):\frac{1}{z}=x$ and $\forall z\in(2,\infty): z\le\exp(\exp(z))$ Therefore: $\forall x\in(0,\frac{1}{2}): \frac{1}{x}=z\ge\log(\log(z))=\log(\log(\frac{1}{x}))=\log(\log(1)-\log(x))=\log(|\log(x)|)$

Answer (score 1):

By letting $r=e^{t}$ the given integral takes the form
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{-\log 2} e^{2t}\log(|t|)\,dt = \int_{\log 2}^{+\infty}\log(t)e^{-2t}\,dt =\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log(t+\log 2)e^{-2t}\,dt$$
and the last integral is clearly convergent, since by convexity we have 
$$\log(t+\log 2) = \log\log 2+\log\left(1+\frac{t}{\log 2}\right)\leq \log\log 2+\frac{t}{\log 2}, $$
for any $t\geq 0$, implying
$$ \left|\int_{0}^{1/2}r \log(|\log r|)\,dr\right| \leq \frac{-\log\log 2}{8}+\frac{1}{16\log 2}.$$